# Find semicolon in between double quotation mark JAVA

Tags: java

I need to split and replace the String by semicolon. I need to find all the semicolons inside the String.

I have some strings or similar to this:

```
"003628;164332;BICICLETA;000000;\"TI;EH.55; MARC;E: 8ʽ7,7542;9ʽ2;,4)\"2015-03-03 12:25:25.0;2016-03-10 09:13:35.0"
```

Here is my code:

```
    String p = "(\"[^\"]+);([^\"]+\")"
    String cad = "003628;164332;BICICLETA;000000;\"TI;EH.55; MARC;E: 8ʽ7,7542;9ʽ2;,4)\"2015-03-03 12:25:25.0;2016-03-10 09:13:35.0"
    Pattern  pat = Pattern.compile(p)
    Matcher  mat = pat.matcher(cad)
    cad.replaceAll(p, "$1#SEMICOLON#$2")
```

the wrong result is :

```
003628;164332;BICICLETA;000000;"TI;EH.55; MARC;E: 8ʽ7,7542;9ʽ2#SEMICOLON#,4)"2015-03-03 12:25:25.0;2016-03-10 09:13:35.0
```

The correct result should be:

```
003628;164332;BICICLETA;000000;"TI#SEMICOLON#EH.55#SEMICOLON# MARC#SEMICOLON#E: 8ʽ7,7542#SEMICOLON#9ʽ2#SEMICOLON#,4)"2015-03-03 12:25:25.0;2016-03-10 09:13:35.0
```

What is wrong with my code? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this without regex as follows:

```
    String cad = "003628;164332;BICICLETA;000000;\"TI;EH.55; MARC;E: 8ʽ7,7542;9ʽ2;,4)\"2015-03-03 12:25:25.0;2016-03-10 09:13:35.0";
    String[] array = cad.split("\"");
    for(int j = 1; j<array.length; j+=2)
    {
        array[j] = array[j].replaceAll(";", "#SEMICOLON#");
    }
    System.out.println(String.join("", array));
```

Result:

003628;164332;BICICLETA;000000;TI#SEMICOLON#EH.55#SEMICOLON# MARC#SEMICOLON#E: 8ʽ7,7542#SEMICOLON#9ʽ2#SEMICOLON#,4)2015-03-03 12:25:25.0;2016-03-10 09:13:35.0

Comment: Thanks !, but this only works in this case.

In another case will fail, for example: 
25674;1530;7;OE00358EST165;;"(5 ;A;XXE: 1ʽ3,33;8ʽ2;,2)";M535i/1;0;0;23/06/2008;15/12/2015

Comment: Hm, it works for me "25674;1530;7;OE00358EST165;;\"(5 ;A;XXE: 1ʽ3,33;8ʽ2;,2)\";M535i/1;0;0;23/06/2008;15/12/2015"; will produce 25674;1530;7;OE00358EST165;;(5 #SEMICOLON#A#SEMICOLON#XXE: 1ʽ3,33#SEMICOLON#8ʽ2#SEMICOLON#,2);M535i/1;0;0;23/06/2008;15/12/2015